# Calculate from SUM of field SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following table:

```
Item       tTotal
------------------
A          20
B          10
C          5
```

I want to have a tsql with a new column, like:

```
Item       tTotal      oPercent
--------------------------------
A          20          57.14
B          10          28.58
C          5           13.3
```

The `oPercent` field calculation is:

```
([tTotal] / [SUM(tTotal)]) * 100
```

Does anyone have an idea for this?
Really appreciated. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using analytic functions, we can do this in a single pass over the table without a formal subquery:

```
SELECT
    Item,
    tTotal,
    100.0 * tTotal / SUM(tTotal) OVER () AS oPercent
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

you use below query

```
DECLARE @TSum INT=0

SELECT @TSum=SUM(tTotal) FROM tablename

SELECT Item,tTotal,((tTotal / @TSum) * 100) AS oPercent FROM tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `CROSS JOIN` since it would produce only one row

```
SELECT
      Item, tTotal,
      100.00 * tTotal/ a.total AS oPercent
FROM table
CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(tTotal) total FROM table)a
```